# Get the MAX, MIN, AVG between two DATES

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I'm trying to query min, max and avg between two dates, that I got from [DATA].

```
SELECT
    MIN([INDEX]) as MIN,
    AVG([INDEX]) as avg,
    MAX([INDEX]) as max
  FROM [data].[dbo].[db_DATA]
```

I tried with the following sql query, but didn't work too.

```
SELECT
    MIN([INDEX]) as MIN,
    AVG([INDEX]) as avg,
    MAX([INDEX]) as max
  FROM [data].[dbo].[db_DATA]
 having MIN([INDEX]) between '2017-02-20' AND '2017-02-25'
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you actually using? The syntax for dates between sql server and access are quite different.

Comment: Also sample data and what you need to get as result can help us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you do not GROUP BY put it in the where clause instead of HAVING. Also remove MIN() because if min is between then max is also and avg is also.

```
SELECT
    MIN([INDEX]) as MIN,
    AVG([INDEX]) as avg,
    MAX([INDEX]) as max
  FROM [data].[dbo].[db_DATA]
 WHERE [INDEX] between '2017-02-20' AND '2017-02-25'
```

Answer (score 1):

the dates is always with '#' if you are working with Ms-access

try like this

```
SELECT
    MIN([INDEX]) as MIN,
    AVG([INDEX]) as avg,
    MAX([INDEX]) as max
  FROM [data].[dbo].[db_DATA]
 having MIN([INDEX]) between #02/20/2017# AND #02/25/2017#
```